# Symfony: Persisting in a "ManyToMany with extra data" after implementing bridge entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, many-to-one, persist

I am trying to persist a "collection" of objects that are related between them through an entity that is in a **ManyToOne** relation with two other entities in order to provide a kind of **"ManyToMany" relation but with extrafields**.

I have followed the only strategy proposed at symfonycasts and also here in stackoverflow by different users which is to *create an entity that will contain as properties the two other entities plus one extra field*.

Users make reservations to a travel on a given date, but such reservations offer different options depending on the travel type.

I make part of the reservation process using javascript and ajax, but yet the problem I have is that my controller will only persist the data from the last item from the array.

The controller's lines where I am encountering the trouble are these:

```
$options = $request->request->get('options') ? $request->request->get('options') : [];
        $dateId = $request->request->get('dateId');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $datesRepository = $em->getRepository(Dates::class);
        $date = $datesRepository->find($dateId);

        $reservation = new Reservation();
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $reservation->setDateAjout($now);
        $reservation->setStatus('initialized');
        $reservation->setDate($date);
        /** INTRODUCING OPTIONS */
        if(count($options) > 0) {
            $reservationOptions = new ReservationOptions();
            $optionsRepository = $em->getRepository(Options::class);
            foreach ( $options as $key => $value ){
                if($value > 0) {
                    $option = $optionsRepository->find($key);
                    $reservationOptions->setOptions($option);
                    $reservationOptions->setAmount($value);
                    $reservation->addReservationOption($reservationOptions);
//This only persist on the last loop
                }
            }
        }
        $em->persist($reservation);
        $em->flush();
```

The entity that relates both entities in a for a "ManyToMany + extra fields" relation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ReservationOptionsRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ReservationOptionsRepository::class)
 */
class ReservationOptions
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *                  targetEntity=Reservation::class, 
     *                  inversedBy="reservationOptions", 
     *                  cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $reservation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *                  targetEntity=Options::class, 
     *                  inversedBy="reservationOptions", 
     *                  cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $amount;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getReservation(): ?Reservation
    {
        return $this->reservation;
    }

    public function setReservation(?Reservation $reservation): self
    {
        $this->reservation = $reservation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOptions(): ?Options
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    public function setOptions(?Options $options): self
    {
        $this->options = $options;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAmount(): ?int
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function setAmount(int $amount): self
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

The reservation entity looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\ReservationRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ReservationRepository::class)
 */
class Reservation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Dates::class, inversedBy="reservations")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="reservations")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ReservationOptions::class, mappedBy="reservation", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $reservationOptions;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->travellers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->reservationOptions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString():string
    {
        return $this->getStatus();
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ReservationOptions[]
     */
    public function getReservationOptions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->reservationOptions;
    }

    public function addReservationOption(ReservationOptions $reservationOption): self
    {
        if (!$this->reservationOptions->contains($reservationOption)) {
            $this->reservationOptions[] = $reservationOption;
            $reservationOption->setReservation($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeReservationOption(ReservationOptions $reservationOption): self
    {
        if ($this->reservationOptions->removeElement($reservationOption)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($reservationOption->getReservation() === $this) {
                $reservationOption->setReservation(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

The options file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Options
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="options")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OptionsRepository")
 */
class Options
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prix", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Travel::class, inversedBy="options")
     */
    private $travel;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=OptionsTranslations::class, mappedBy="options", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $optionsTranslations;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ReservationOptions::class, mappedBy="options", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $reservationOptions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->optionsTranslations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->reservationOptions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?string
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(string $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTravel(): ?Travel
    {
        return $this->travel;
    }

    public function setTravel(?Travel $travel): self
    {
        $this->travel = $travel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OptionsTranslations[]
     */
    public function getOptionsTranslations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->optionsTranslations;
    }

    public function addOptionsTranslation(OptionsTranslations $optionsTranslation): self
    {
        if (!$this->optionsTranslations->contains($optionsTranslation)) {
            $this->optionsTranslations[] = $optionsTranslation;
            $optionsTranslation->setOptions($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOptionsTranslation(OptionsTranslations $optionsTranslation): self
    {
        if ($this->optionsTranslations->removeElement($optionsTranslation)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($optionsTranslation->getOptions() === $this) {
                $optionsTranslation->setOptions(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString():string
    {
        return $this->travel->getMainTitle();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ReservationOptions[]
     */
    public function getReservationOptions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->reservationOptions;
    }

    public function addReservationOption(ReservationOptions $reservationOption): self
    {
        if (!$this->reservationOptions->contains($reservationOption)) {
            $this->reservationOptions[] = $reservationOption;
            $reservationOption->setOptions($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeReservationOption(ReservationOptions $reservationOption): self
    {
        if ($this->reservationOptions->removeElement($reservationOption)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($reservationOption->getOptions() === $this) {
                $reservationOption->setOptions(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same `ReservationOptions` entity, changing the option and value on each iteration of the loop. So, you end up with only one `ReservationOptions` having the values from the last item.
You need to create a `new ReservationOptions` entity for each option/value.

```
    /** INTRODUCING OPTIONS */
    if(count($options) > 0) {
        $optionsRepository = $em->getRepository(Options::class);
        foreach ( $options as $key => $value ){
            if($value > 0) {
                $reservationOptions = new ReservationOptions();
                $option = $optionsRepository->find($key);
                $reservationOptions->setOptions($option);
                $reservationOptions->setAmount($value);
                $reservation->addReservationOption($reservationOptions);
            }
        }
    }
    $em->persist($reservation);
    $em->flush();
```